Elkay water fountain with cooling
Is it permitted to use cooled water from a water fountain on Shabbos and Yom Tov because the device works similar to a refrigirator and considered as "grama"?
Elkay is the most popular brand of water fountains.
There are no lights on the unit and it takes about 30 sec for the electric cooling unit to be activated after water disperses.

Is the question about using the water that a melacha may have been done to, or accessing the water (eg. in a way that will make the motor turn back on again or do some other melacha)? Every water fountain's mechanism could be different and you have to evaluate each case on its own. Sometimes the open switch turns on a light or is electric in other ways, for instance.

What is "Alkay"?

Sign once seen in a yeshiva: "do not use this water fountain on shabbos, and do not write opposing marei mekomos on this paper!"

I've seen the opposite notice: that it is permitted to use the water fountain on Shabbat.

@ClintEastwood precisely. There is ample room to be lenient, assuming the only concern is that the cooling unit will turn on every so often. But rather than the yeshiva simply advising people to be strict, they preferred for them to be uninformed and afraid.

Welcome to MiYodeya Eugene and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
